# I have a function extracting .JPG from sharepoint URL's but when I use it the data is unreadable

Tags: excel, xml, vba, url

'This code generates files that cannot be opened

```
Sub DownloadPicturestoFile()

Dim FileUrl As String
Dim objXmlHttpReq As Object
Dim objStream As Object
Dim NamingVariable As String
Dim RowLoc As Integer
Dim FileNum As Integer
RowLoc = 2
FileNum = 1
Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowLoc, 1) = ""
FileUrl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowLoc, 6)
NamingVariable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowLoc, 1) & " - " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowLoc, 2)
NamingVariable = Replace(NamingVariable, "/", "_")
NamingVariable = Replace(NamingVariable, "\", "_")
NamingVariable = Replace(NamingVariable, "~", "_")
NamingVariable = Replace(NamingVariable, "#", "_")
NamingVariable = Replace(NamingVariable, ":", "_")
NamingVariable = Replace(NamingVariable, "<", "_")
NamingVariable = Replace(NamingVariable, ">", "_")
NamingVariable = Replace(NamingVariable, "?", "_")
NamingVariable = Replace(NamingVariable, "|", "_")
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowLoc, 6) <> "" Then
Set objXmlHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

objXmlHttpReq.Open "GET", FileUrl, False, "", ""
objXmlHttpReq.send

If objXmlHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
     Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
     objStream.Open
     objStream.Type = 1
     objStream.write objXmlHttpReq.responseBody
     objStream.savetofile ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Pictures\" & NamingVariable & "-" & FileNum & ".jpg", 2
     objStream.Close
End If
RowLoc = RowLoc + 1
Else
RowLoc = RowLoc + 1
End If
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowLoc, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowLoc - 1, 2) Then
FileNum = FileNum + 1
Else
FileNum = 1
End If
Loop
End Sub
```

'This code generates files that can be opened but gives access denied whenever it's not my own personal sharepoint where the files are stored (even if I have access) The weird thing about the code below is that it did work at first even when the URL was not my own sharepoint location.

```
Sub Save_image()
Dim oHTTP As Object
Dim sDestFolder As String
Dim sSrcUrl As String
Dim sImageFile As String
Dim RowLoc As Integer
Dim NamingVariable As String
Dim FileNum As Integer
FileNum = 1
RowLoc = 2
Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowLoc, 1) = ""
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowLoc, 6) <> "" Then
    
NamingVariable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowLoc, 1) & " - " & 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowLoc, 2) & FileNum
NamingVariable = Replace(NamingVariable, "/", "_")
NamingVariable = Replace(NamingVariable, "\", "_")
NamingVariable = Replace(NamingVariable, "~", "_")
NamingVariable = Replace(NamingVariable, "#", "_")
NamingVariable = Replace(NamingVariable, ":", "_")
NamingVariable = Replace(NamingVariable, "<", "_")
NamingVariable = Replace(NamingVariable, ">", "_")
NamingVariable = Replace(NamingVariable, "?", "_")
NamingVariable = Replace(NamingVariable, "|", "_")
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowLoc, 2) = 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowLoc - 1, 2) Then
FileNum = FileNum + 1
Else
FileNum = 1
End If
sDestFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Pictures\" & NamingVariable & "-" & FileNum & ".jpg"
sSrcUrl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowLoc, 6)


sImageFile = Right(ActiveCell.Value, Len(ActiveCell.Value) - InStrRev(ActiveCell.Value, "/"))
Debug.Print sImageFile
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = sImageFile


Set oHTTP = CreateObject("msxml2.XMLHTTP")
oHTTP.Open "GET", sSrcUrl, False
oHTTP.send

Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
oStream.Type = adTypeBinary
oStream.Open

oStream.write oHTTP.responseBody
oStream.savetofile sDestFolder & ".jpg", adSaveCreateOverWrite

Set oStream = Nothing
Set oHTTP = Nothing
RowLoc = RowLoc + 1
Else
RowLoc = RowLoc + 1
End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: it's really puzzling because some URL's work and almost identical ones don't seem to. even though I can open both in a browser. 

this URL downloads fine
https://pearltechnology207-my.sharepoint.com/personal/scott_cannon_pearltechnology_com/Documents/Apps/Microsoft%20Forms/Job%20Equipment%20and%20Received%20Inventory/Question/image_First%20Last%2066.jpg

This one gives access denied
https://pearltechnology207-my.sharepoint.com/personal/scott_cannon_pearltechnology_com/Documents/Apps/Microsoft%20Forms/Job%20Equipment%20and%20Received%20Inventory/Question/image_First%20Last%2046.jpg

Comment: Better to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72233780/edit) instead of using comments to add information to your question